# BitBucket pipeline is not using cache for npm install

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a single BitBucket repository containing the code for an Angular app in a folder called `ui` and a Node API in a folder called `api`.

My BitBucket pipeline runs `ng test` for the Angular app, but the `node_modules` folder isn't being cached correctly.

This is my BitBucket Pipeline yml file:

```
image: trion/ng-cli-karma

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - angular-node
        script:
          - cd ui
          - npm install
          - ng test --watch=false

definitions:
  caches:
    angular-node: /ui/node_modules
```

When the builds runs it shows:

```
Cache "angular-node": Downloading
Cache "angular-node": Extracting
Cache "angular-node": Extracted
```

But when it performs the `npm install` step it says:

> added 1623 packages in 41.944s

I am trying to speed the build up and I can't work out why npm needs to install the dependencies assuming they are already contained in the cache which has been restored.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

my guess is, your cache position is not correct. <strike>there is a pre-configured node cache (named "node") that can just be activated. no need to do a custom cache for that.</strike> (the default cache fails, because your node build is in a sub folder of the clone directory, so you need a custom cache)

cache positons are relative to the clone directory. bitbucket clones into `/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build` thats probably why your absolute cache-path did not work.

simply making the cache reference relative should do the trick

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
        - angular-node
        script:
        - cd ui
        - npm install
        - ng test --watch=false
definitions:
  caches:
    angular-node: ui/node_modules
```

that may fix your issue

Comment: Does the preconfigured cache not look in node_modules rather than the subfolder?

Comment: after reading the documentation aggain (https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/caching-dependencies-895552876.html) i think your initial Approach was correct but you should use a relative path (take the leading / away) as your clone path is not at top level. the default node cache does not work because your project uses a subfolder. i will update my answer